# Python group and sum

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a list of tuples:

```
Listoftuples=[
    (0.021892733407683305, 0.14887058717224647, 4.573173081530965, 0.04619366749021177, u'0102'),
    (0.08416364174734663, 0.8500527816482009, 23.649983331004403, 0.0, u'0103'),
    (0.02181070623592521, 0.15049387302788395, 1.2098398749067714, 1.6037412295275804, u'0102')
    ]
```

I want to per group (group = last value in tuple, for example u'0102'):

- Summarize first value
- Summarize second value and divide by sum of  first value

Attempt:

```
import itertools

Listoftuples=[
    (0.021892733407683305, 0.14887058717224647, 4.573173081530965, 0.04619366749021177, u'0102'),
    (0.08416364174734663, 0.8500527816482009, 23.649983331004403, 0.0, u'0103'),
    (0.02181070623592521, 0.15049387302788395, 1.2098398749067714, 1.6037412295275804, u'0102')
    ]

keyfunc=lambda t: (t[4])
Listoftuples.sort(key=keyfunc)

for key,rows in itertools.groupby(Listoftuples, keyfunc):
    sumOfFirstValue = sum(r[0] for r in rows)
    sumOfSecondDividedBySumOfFirst= sum(r[1] for r in rows)/sumOfFirstValue
    print key,sumOfFirstValue,sumOfSecondDividedBySumOfFirst
```

Results:

```
0102 0.0437034396436 0.0
0103 0.0841636417473 0.0
```

Zero values in last. How can i fix it?

Comment: `rows` is an iterator. Convert it to a list before performing operations on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A common mistake is to think that `rows` returned from `groupby` is a concrete list. Actually it's an iterator and is exhausted while calculating `sumOfFirstValue`. A workaround is:

```
...
for key,rows in itertools.groupby(Listoftuples, keyfunc):
    rows = list(rows)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution without using `itertools`:

```
groups = set(item[4] for item in Listoftuples)
for g in groups:
    sum_first_val = sum([item[0] for item in Listoftuples if item[4] == g])
    sum_second_val = sum([item[1] for item in Listoftuples if item[4] == g])
    print g, sum_first_val, sum_second_val / sum_first_val
```